Reload linux user groups from a Golang automation script
We have a Go automation script which creates Linux users, the script runs under a different user, called scriptuser but this script uses exec.Command to create new users. The problem is we want to add the user scriptuser inside the newly created user's group, so that the scriptuser can read/write into the user's home directory whenever it needs to make new changes. We are able to add the scriptuser to the newly created user's group without any issues but the script user's groups are not being changed unless we logout and log back in from the shell. How can we achieve this without logging out and logging back in.
NOTE: scriptuser has sudo privileges
The below code is run with the user scriptuser
Example code

func setupUser(username string) {
  cmd,err := exec.Command("sudo", "useradd","-m",username)
  cmd.Run() 
  if err!=nil {
  // handle error
 }
  
 cmd,err exec.Command("sudo","chmod","g+w","/home/"+username) // provide write perms at a group level

 
 cmd, err = exec.Command("sudo", "adduser", "scriptuser", username) // add scriptuser to the newly created user's group
    out, err = cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
     
    os.Create("/home/"+username + "/sample.txt") // get a permission denied error even though I have added `scriptuser` as part of the new user's group, that is because scriptuser's groups have not been reloaded yet.
 
}

I tried adding exec.Command("newgrp", "<new_user_group>") and exec.Command("newgrp") in sequence but it did not reload the groups.

Groups for the process user are set at login. You could execute a new shell again as that user. See https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out, https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-refresh-reload-group-membership-without-logging-reboot/, https://serverfault.com/questions/74934/refresh-supplementary-group-memberships-without-logging-in-again, for some of the top google results
